# create data frame based on unique values of two variables in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, uniqueidentifier, reshape2

I would like to create a new data frame based on two unique values from another data frame.

```
id <- c("A", "B", "B", "C")
st.name <- c("TX", "TX", "CA", "CA") 
type <- c(21, 26, 29, 24)
DF <- data.frame(id, st.name, type)
print(DF)

id st.name type  
A      TX   21  
B      TX   26  
B      CA   29  
C      CA   24
```

I would like to create an new data frame based on the unique values of id and st.type. The result would look like:

```
new_id <- c("ATX", "ACA", "BTX", "BCA", "CTX", "CCA")
new_type <- c(21, NA, 26, 29, NA, 24)
DF2 <- data.frame(new_id, new_type)
print(DF2)

new_id new_type  
ATX       21  
ACA       NA  
BTX       26  
BCA       29  
CTX       NA  
CCA       24
```

I have used `dcast` in previous projects, but I am not sure how to incorporate the function here.

Comment: Amazing! thank you @akrun

Answer (score 4):

We can do this with `complete` and `unite` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
complete(DF, id, st.name) %>% 
              unite(new_id, id, st.name, sep = '')
```

---

Or using `base R`, we can get the expected output with `expand.grid`, `merge` and `paste`

```
transform(merge(expand.grid(lapply(DF[1:2], unique)),
             DF, all.x=TRUE), id = paste0(id, st.name))[-2]
```

---

Or a `data.table` option with `CJ` (mentioned by @Frank in the comments)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[CJ(id = id, st.name = st.name, unique=TRUE), on=.(id, st.name)]
```

Comment: Beautiful. Tiny note: `unite` takes a `sep` argument, so `unite(new_id, id, st.name, sep='')` will give no separator as in the OP's (updated) example. Or whatever `sep` we land on.

Comment: I guess the data.table analogue for your merge is something like `setDT(DF)[CJ(id = id, st.name = st.name, unique=TRUE), on=.(id, st.name)]`